# What is $\cos(x)+\sin(x)$ as a function of $\cos(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a trigonometric function explaining $\cos(x)+\sin(x)$? if not, what is $\cos(x)+\sin(x)$ as a function of $\cos(x)$?

Comment: What have you tried and what things you think could be helpful here? Adding context and some attempt will make your questions better received and more useful to you.

Comment: This is a [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations) of sine and cosine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt 2 \cos (x-\pi/4)$$

By the [Prostaphaeresis-Simpson-formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html). If you need, you can convert sinuses into cosinuses via $\sin x =\cos(\pi/2-x)$.

---

Actually there is another fun way to see that this formula is true.

As you may know, if you take a point on the plane, located at an angle x with respect to the reference axis, then $(\cos x, \sin x)$ are proportional to the Cartesian coordinates of the point.

So your formula is is proportional to the sum of the coordinates of the point. This is basically equivalent (up to a proportionality constant) to compute a coordinate of your point with respect to an orthogonal Cartesian system that is rotated by an angle of 45 degrees.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for, $\sqrt{2}cos(x - pi/4)$ but how have you found it?

Comment: Sure! I found it by the Prostaphaeresis-Simpson-formula. Remember, you can convert sinuses into cosinuses via sinx=cos(π/2−x).

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\cos{x}+\sin{x}=\cos{x}+\cos{(\frac\pi2-x)}$.

You may keep it as it is, or you may apply the formula for $\cos{C}+\cos{D}$ according to your needs.

Another representation may also be $\cos{x}+\sin{x}=\cos{x}+\sqrt{1-\cos^2{x}}$. But in this case, as N.F. Taussig pointed out, we will have cases (with respect to in which quadrant $x$ lies) according to when to take the negative root, and when to take the positive one.

Does that help?

Comment: $\sin x = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2x}$ only when $\sin x \geq 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, but we will have cases (with respect to in which quadrant $x$ lies) according to when to take the negative root, and when to take the positive one.